# log4j library is not writing in a file

Tags: log4j

Why this code is not writing to a file? Instead write to file is writing in console:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,dante

log4j.appender.dante=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.dante.File=mylog.log

log4j.appender.dante.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dante.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: Can you show a sample code using the logger?

Comment: `private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApp.class);      logger.debug("Testing log4j...")`

Comment: it seems that the logger is taking the configuration of a log4j.xml found in a jar of Storm distribution. I've tried to force to read my application file log4.properties but with no luck.. any idea?

Comment: You should be able to tell your jar to use a specific log configuration by doing `java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.properties jar MyApp.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that I was trying to apply log4j in my application importing the log4j libraries when Storm is doing this for me. So, at the end, I've used the log4j configuration of Storm that can be changed in the Storm UI, ;).